# If Else not working in JFrame

Tags: jframe

```
if (!(tf_category_mt.getText().trim().equals("")
     && tf_cat_desc_mt.getText().trim().equals(""))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fail");
}
```

Here `if` and `else` are not working.
`tf_category_mt` and `tf_cat_desc` are two text fields.

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: I think that is a problem with that JFrame. nothing is working in that

Comment: Have you used any debugging? - what were the results

Comment: A short advice: move the line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");` before the `if` clause and check whether the dialog does appear or not.